# Eclipse Che not starting up

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, docker, eclipse-che

I recently tried installing Eclipse Che on Windows 10, 64 bit. I installed all of the pre-reqs, but when I ran `che.bat`, it gave me the following message:

[image]

What can I do to fix the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error is due to spaces in the path name on Windows. We just issued a fix for this, but in looking at the error, it seems like some of the paths had their spaces fixed and some did not.

It would be helpful if you can open a ticket on [github.com/codenvy/che](https://github.com/eclipse/che) (use github issues).  Please provide:

1. The OS you are using
2. Which Che version you installed (what day)
3. The directory name that you placed che into (full name).

We will see if you have the latest fix, and if you do, then we need to understand what is unique about your directory names to fix this.

BTW, you can fix this immediately by just moving the Che directory to any other directory without a space.

Comment: For that matter, don't put it under `Program Files`. File permissions behave oddly there.